# Does AutoMapper map complex entity ids automagically?

Tags: c#, automapper

In my code, AutoMapper is doing something that I actively don't want it to do and, worse, I can't see any reason why.

Consider these model classes:

```
public class PersonSource
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public ContactSource Contact { get; set; }
}

public class ContactSource
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class PersonDestination
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public Contact Contact { get; set; }
}

public class ContactDestination
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public ContactDestination Contact { get; set; }
    public int ContactId { get; set; }
}
```

This is for use with Entity Framework.

A person has a contact. The source `Person` has a `Contact` object that's just the complex object. This is mapped to a destination `Person` that has both the destination `Contact` **AND** a `ContactId`.

When I call the `Map` method, `personDestination.ContactId` is populated with `sourcePerson.Contact.Id`, and nothing anywhere in my mapping or config, AFAICT, asks it to do this (and I don't want it to do so, for business logic reasons).

What's going on here and how do I prevent it?

Comment: This might be related to "Flattening", see https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Flattening.html

Comment: @Progman This is exactly what is happening, and this behavior can be disabled by setting `cfg.DestinationMemberNamingConvention = new ExactMatchNamingConvention();`, although this is true for the whole configuration and I can't tell how to enable this granularly for one mapping. Can you write this as an answer so I can accept it?